# Cannot Reference LVL Android Library in my App Project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lvl

I'm following the instructions found at http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

I made a copy of the <sdk>/market_licensing directory, then using the New Project Wizard in Eclipse I created a new Android project from Existing source and pointed it at the library subdirectory in my copy of market_licensing.

I've checked the "is Library" box in the market_licensing project android properties.
I've added that project as a library project in my app project. It shows up in the list with a green checkmark.

When I save the project settings and rebuild, the compiler can't find the classes in the LVL project and when I go back into my app's project settings the entry in the libraries list now has a red X instead of the green checkmark.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong which is preventing me from referencing the LVL project. Any help?

EDIT: I've tried adding the licensing project to my build path for my app project and then I'm able to build, but when I try to run the app crashes because it can't find any of the library code. So clearly the "library" status of the licensing project is not set up correctly and/or its not being automatically injected into my app project on build.

Comment: +1 for being on the same boat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was posting up a similar question and as I did so realised what the problem was - see here [In eclipse, unable to reference an android library project in another android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pro)

Comment: I'm swamped and not able to test if this fixes my problem at the moment, but when I get an hour or so to dive into this I'll try it out.